# Can a level 6 draconic sorcerer add their Charisma modifier to Chaos Bolt?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer

In D&D 5e, [Draconic Sorcerers](http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/sorcerer:draconic-bloodline), at level 6, gain the ability to add their Charisma modifier to one damage roll of any spell they cast that deals the damage type associated with their Dragon Ancestor.

Suppose a sorcerer has a Blue Dragon ancestor, associated with lightning damage. Can they add their Charisma modifier to [Chaos Bolt](http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/spell:chaos-bolt), even if lightning damage isn't rolled in that casting? The spell itself can deal lightning damage, but not always.

Comment: Related: "[Is Heart of the Storm triggered by spells that may or may not deal lightning or thunder damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123198)"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Elemental Affinity applies only if  you roll the right damage type.

Elemental Affinity says you can add the extra damage

> when you cast a spell that deals damage of the type associated with your
> draconic ancestry

It doesn't say "a spell that *can* deal damage of the type associated". Only the damage the spell *actually deals* will count.

If you cast *Chaos Bolt* and it deals fire damage, you have obviously not cast a spell that deals lightning damage.